# Generating checkboxes in html tables from query results

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, html-table

I'm trying to generate a table with checkboxes on each row. I have found a working code below for generating a table based on query results. Is it possible to insert a code in here which will provide an extra column which will contain checkboxes in each row?

```
<?php

    function SQLResultTable($Query)
    {
        $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root" , "") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());      //build MySQL Link
        mysql_select_db("dbName") or die('Could not select database');        //select database
        $Table = "";  //initialize table variable

        $Table.= "<table border='1' style=\"border-collapse: collapse;\">"; //Open HTML Table

        $Result = mysql_query($Query); //Execute the query
        if(mysql_error())
        {
            $Table.= "<tr><td>MySQL ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "</td></tr>";
        }
        else
        {
            //Header Row with Field Names
            $NumFields = mysql_num_fields($Result);
            $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; color: #FFFFFF;\">";
            for ($i=0; $i < $NumFields; $i++)
            {
                $Table.= "<th>" . mysql_field_name($Result, $i) . "</th>";
            }
            $Table.= "</tr>";

            //Loop thru results
            $RowCt = 0; //Row Counter
            while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
            {
                //Alternate colors for rows
                if($RowCt++ % 2 == 0) $Style = "background-color: #FFCCCC;";
                else $Style = "background-color: #FFFFFF;";

                $Table.= "<tr style=\"$Style\">";
                //Loop thru each field
                foreach($Row as $field => $value)
                {
                    $Table.= "<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp$value&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>";
                }
                $Table.= "</tr>";
            }

        }
        $Table.= "</table>";

        return $Table;
    }

?>
```

Comment: I suggest you use your favourite search engine and look for a) a PHP tutorial b) an HTML tutorial ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want it as the last column in each row:

```
<?php

        function SQLResultTable($Query)
        {
            $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root" , "") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());      //build MySQL Link
            mysql_select_db("dbName") or die('Could not select database');        //select database
            $Table = "";  //initialize table variable

            $Table.= "<table border='1' style=\"border-collapse: collapse;\">"; //Open HTML Table

            $Result = mysql_query($Query); //Execute the query
            if(mysql_error())
            {
                $Table.= "<tr><td>MySQL ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "</td></tr>";
            }
            else
            {
                //Header Row with Field Names
                $NumFields = mysql_num_fields($Result);
                $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; color: #FFFFFF;\">";
                for ($i=0; $i < $NumFields; $i++)
                {
                    $Table.= "<th>" . mysql_field_name($Result, $i) . "</th>";
                }
                $Table.= "<th>Checkbox column</th>";
                $Table.= "</tr>";

                //Loop thru results
                $RowCt = 0; //Row Counter
                while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
                {
                    //Alternate colors for rows
                    if($RowCt++ % 2 == 0) $Style = "background-color: #FFCCCC;";
                    else $Style = "background-color: #FFFFFF;";

                    $Table.= "<tr style=\"$Style\">";
                    //Loop thru each field
                    foreach($Row as $field => $value)
                    {
                        $Table.= "<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp$value&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>";
                        $Table.= "<td><input type="checkbox" name="nameHere" value="valueHere" ></td>";
                    }
                    $Table.= "</tr>";
                }

            }
            $Table.= "</table>";

            return $Table;
        }
?>
```

Though the code's that's generated is really ugly - inline styles, ugh. -_-

Answer (score 0):

its a very simply logic, excuse me i don't use your complete code:

**index.php:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>your page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <table>
        <caption>myTable</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>column with checkbox</th>
            <th>column with text</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php
            // get your databaseresult to an array called $result
            $connection = mysql_connect("server", "user", "password");
            mysql_select_database("databasename");
            $resultHash = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultHash)){
               $result[] = $row;
            }
            mysql_close($connection); // never forget to close the connection if not longer needed

            foreach($result as $key => $value)
            {
              echo "<tr>\r\n";
              echo "  <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"yourCheckboxName".$key."\" /></td>\r\m";
              // $key is the index of your numeric $result array
              echo "  <td>".$value[0]."</td>\r\n";
              echo "</tr>\r\n";
            }
          ?>
        <tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
<html>
```

That is simply all you need to do I think, and please work with `mysql_fetch_array()`
`http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php` it's even faster

I hope the code is correct, if not look what the arrays `$result` and `$value` are like by using `var_dump()`. Didn't test it and didn't write php 4 weeks or something like this

Edit:
I did a mistake last night, sorry, here is a little correction.

I think your database table design is like.

**table(id int auto_increment, something varchar(255) not null, primary key(id))**

```
<?php
  foreach($result as $index => $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
      echo "<input type='checkbox' name='yourname".$index."' />"; // now every checkbox has an unique identifier
    echo "</td>";
    foreach($row as $column => $value){
      echo "<td>";
      echo "column = ".$column;
      echo "\r\n";
      echo "value = ".$value;
      echo "<td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
?>
```